# Run tests using different env. variables depending on a command in package.json

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

Trying to find a common practice solution of how to run tests depending on test command in package.json with corresponding environment variables from .env file.

.env. //file

```
BASE_URL=dev
BASE_URL=stage
API_DEV=api-dev
API_STG=api-stage
```

package.json //file

```
"test:dev": "mocha ...",
"test:stage": "mocha ...",
```

Launching **test:dev** I want to fetch for my tests all variables for DEV environment.

Can I configure it like that?

Comment: I think you can simply pass an env variable along with your command and read that in your later scirpt: `"test:dev": "APP_ENV=dev mocha ..."` and access the variable `process.env.APP_ENV` in your script to detect env and prepare necessary configurations.

Comment: @ma Thanks for the answer, but trying it I can't succeed, maybe I'm doing something wrong. I have 2 files: .env and .env.stage and when I run ```"test:stage": "env=stage mocha"``` it runs variables from .env anyways instead of .env.stage. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: though, maybe I got it, will try right now

Comment: Ok, I changed it, but still doesn't work.
I added variables ```APP_ENV={env}``` into ```.env``` and ```.env.stage.```
But in my config files, I have process.env.{var} everywhere so I simply I guess doesn't see .env.stage when I run  ```"test:stage": "env=stage mocha"``` because it's in .env.stage...

Answer (score 2):

Lets say your `package.json` contains the following scripts property-

```
"test:local": "APP_ENV=local mocha ...",
"test:dev": "APP_ENV=dev mocha ...",
"test:stage": "APP_ENV=stage mocha ...",
"test:prod": "APP_ENV=prod mocha ..."
```

And lets assume you have the following files: `.env` for `prod`, `.env.stage` for `stage` and `.env.dev` for `dev` environment.

Now in your script you can dynamically load the `env` files using `dotenv` package.

```
switch (process.env.APP_ENV) {
    case 'dev':
        env_suffix = ".dev";
        break;
    case 'stage':
        env_suffix = ".stage";
        break;
    case 'local':
        env_suffix = ".local";
        break;
}

require("dotenv").config({
    path: path.join(__dirname + "/../", ".env" + env_suffix)
});
```

In this way you can have the environment variables in your `process.env` object

Comment: Hi maksbd19! Thank you for your answer. It's a good one but I already figured out how to it in some laconic way, I will post it in the answer:-)

Comment: Hi maksbd19, this worked a charm, thank you so much for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it like that:

In `config` folder I have 
`.env`
`stage.env`
`prod.env`

and have `index.js` file where:

```
const {NODE_ENV = 'dev'} = process.env;
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config({path: `${__dirname}/${NODE_ENV}.env`});

module.exports = {

    api: {
        url: dotenv.parsed.API_BASE || ''
    },

    elastic: {
        host: dotenv.parsed.ELASTIC_HOST || ''
    }
};
```

and in package json I have:

```
"elastic:dev": "mocha ./test/elasticsearch/*.js",
"elastic:stage": "NODE_ENV=stage mocha ./test/elasticsearch/*.js",
"elastic:prod": "NODE_ENV=prod mocha ./test/elasticsearch/*.js"
```

Easy and pretty dry way to start tests aka like a boss depending on the environment.